# Check for each image if it's visible. If none is visible, do something

Tags: jquery, each

```js
$("img").each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':hidden')) {
        $("p#nothing").show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imgWrap">
<img src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2012/V/0/1/p/9396/326/800/9396326800_4_1_4.jpg" class="fashion black" alt="">
<img src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2012/V/0/1/p/9396/323/401/9396323401_4_1_4.jpg" class="fashion" alt="">
<img src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2012/V/0/1/p/9396/306/622/9396306622_4_1_4.jpg" class="fashion pink" alt="">
<img src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2012/V/0/1/p/5396/361/707/5396361707_4_1_4.jpg" class="fashion brown" alt="">
<img src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2012/V/0/1/p/5396/302/800/5396302800_4_1_4.jpg" class="fashion pink" alt="">
<img src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2012/V/0/1/p/5396/377/800/5396377800_4_1_4.jpg" class="fashion black" alt="">
<img src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2012/V/0/1/p/5396/349/725/5396349725_4_1_4.jpg" class="fashion beige" alt="">
<img src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2012/V/0/1/p/5639/306/401/5639306401_4_1_4.jpg" class="jumpsuit blue" alt="">
</div>
```

```
$("img").each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':hidden')) {
        $("p#nothing").show();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="imgWrap">
<img src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2012/V/0/1/p/9396/326/800/9396326800_4_1_4.jpg" class="fashion black" alt="">
<img src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2012/V/0/1/p/9396/323/401/9396323401_4_1_4.jpg" class="fashion" alt="">
<img src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2012/V/0/1/p/9396/306/622/9396306622_4_1_4.jpg" class="fashion pink" alt="">
<img src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2012/V/0/1/p/5396/361/707/5396361707_4_1_4.jpg" class="fashion brown" alt="">
<img src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2012/V/0/1/p/5396/302/800/5396302800_4_1_4.jpg" class="fashion pink" alt="">
<img src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2012/V/0/1/p/5396/377/800/5396377800_4_1_4.jpg" class="fashion black" alt="">
<img src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2012/V/0/1/p/5396/349/725/5396349725_4_1_4.jpg" class="fashion beige" alt="">
<img src="http://static.pullandbear.net/2/photos/2012/V/0/1/p/5639/306/401/5639306401_4_1_4.jpg" class="jumpsuit blue" alt="">
</div>

<p id="nothing">No products were found that matched your filters</p>
```

This doesn't work but I really can't find out why. What needs to happen: check all images whether they are visible. If none of them is visible, show a paragraph.

Thanks.

Comment: it should work, can you post the html?

Comment: @undefined : Added HTML.

Comment: Your HTML doesn't have any hidden images.

Comment: They are initially hidden by CSS, then fadeINn by jQuery and then tey can be hidden or shown by the use of filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use selector to find out the img controls which are visible. `$("img:visible")` gives you array of jQuery img objects those are visible. By checking the length we find out the how many img controls are visible and `length = 0` mean no element is returned by the selector `means none of img is visible`.

```
if($("img:visible").length == 0)
{
  //show graph
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bram Vanroy, I have updated the answer, Please do not hesitate if you have any queries.

Answer (score 1):

What your code does is to show the paragraph if any of the images is hidden, what you want is to show it if all are hidden:

```
var shown = false;
$("img").each(function() {
  if($(this).is(':hidden')) {
    shown = true;
  }
});
if (!shown) {
  $("p#nothing").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if ($("img:hidden").length > 0) {
    $("p#nothing").show();
}
```